# I can't verify my condition by using a list, what can i do?

Tags: python

I'm actully codiding a twitch bot and i need to verify if the `Message.author` is a moderator
So i do this :

```
    @commands.command()
    async def off(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        Modo = ["Lilkoroo"]
        print(Modo)
        if twitchio.Message.author == Modo:
            print("a")
```

but nothing work when i try the command

Comment: Why are you using a list? And if you are using a list why not use the `in` condition?

Comment: Where can i put `in` ?
And it's because information come from an api where i put username in, i just simplify it for me .

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Check out the answer below, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, your statement:

```
if twitchio.Message.author == f'{Modo}':
```

is evaluated to...

```
if twitchio.Message.author == '["Lilkoroo"]':
```

Which wouldn't work, because nobody has the username '["Lilkoroo"]'. I assume what you want to do is check that the author's name is found in the list, which you can do with:

```
if twitchio.Message.author in Modo:
```

This will evaluate true if the author is found in the array Modo

Comment: Is unfortunately not working or i do something wrong which would be more logical so i had : 

        Modo = ["Lilkoroo"]
        print(Modo)
        if twitchio.Message.author in Modo:
            print("a")